# Where to get UniObjects for .NET?

Tags: .net, unidata, uniobjects

I hate IBM's site. It is extremely hard to find anything on there let alone try to find it twice!

I'm looking for the UniObjects for .NET. I did find the below files and have installed them (can't find them now on IBM's website) however when I go to install the database add-ins for Visual Studio (v9.7) it says the IBM Data Server Provider for .Net isn't installed.

I'm looking for someone to point me to links and steps to get the Add-Ins for Visual Studio installed and so that I can be able to connect to a UniData database. Any other pointers, tips, or tricks for working with .NET and UniData would also be appreciative.

Here are the files I've installed with no avail. (I'm on a 64 bit Windows XP machine)

1. ibm_data_server_client_winx64_V97.zip
2. ibm_data_server_driver_package_win64_EN_v97.exe
3. v9.5fp4_ntx64_dsdriver_EN.exe
4. v9.5fp4_ntx64_rtcl_EN.exe
5. ibm_database_addins_for_visualstudio_v97.exe

-Thanks

**Update 2010-11-14:** IBM sold UniData to RocketSoftware a while ago. UniObjects info at RocketSoftware can be found http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/middleware/

Comment: Also see the detailed links, on UniData and .NET, at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786413/college-software-development-getting-data-out-of-datatel-colleague/786537#786537

Comment: The latest place to find the download is http://info.rocketsoftware.com/u2-ClientDownloads.html (May 2014). You need to fill out the details and a link is e-mailed to you with the download location.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UniObjects.NET is part of the UniDK on the Client Tools CD.  Look for a directory called "uonet" after you run the install.  Also, you have to set the reference to the UniObjects assembly in your .NET project by browsing to the DLL in your project.  After that, it's a matter of reading the docs, etc.  One thing that took me a while to figure out was that when specifying the account you want to connect to, you need to include the full path, starting with a slash.  (Assuming you are on Unix--I have no experience with Unidata on Windows.)  I'm adding Unidata to my tags, so post additional questions here...